# dangerouslySetInnerHTML in <td> not working when placing content inside <td>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use dangerously dangerouslySetInnerHTML in my React project. I am using it with  in my table. I want to place some  also inside td.

Table rows doesn't show up when I do this

```
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.words}}>
<div className={commentClassName}>
    <div className="comments-item">
        <div className="comments-item-dp">
        </div>
        <div className="comments-item-text">
            <span>APURV</span>
            Delete the marked words from this part
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="comments-item">
        <div className="comments-item-dp">
        </div>
        <div className="comments-item-text">
            <span>APURV</span>
            Mute this when aired at prime time.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="comments-item">
        <div className="comments-item-dp">
        </div>
        <div className="comments-item-text">
            <span>ROHAN</span>
            <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="Add comment ..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it works when I do this

```
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.words}}></td>
```

I want to place that div inside it. How can I make it work?

Comment: You want both together? Why don't you add `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.words}}></div>` _inside_ your `<td>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the TD innerhtml you are replacing all it's content. If you have, lets say, a div inside it, it will be replaced by the new content.

The easy way to fix it would be apply a div for the dynamic content inside your td:

```
<td>
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.words}}></div>
<div className={commentClassName}>
    <div className="comments-item">
        <div className="comments-item-dp">
        </div>
        <div className="comments-item-text">
            <span>APURV</span>
            Delete the marked words from this part
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="comments-item">
        <div className="comments-item-dp">
        </div>
        <div className="comments-item-text">
            <span>APURV</span>
            Mute this when aired at prime time.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="comments-item">
        <div className="comments-item-dp">
        </div>
        <div className="comments-item-text">
            <span>ROHAN</span>
            <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="Add comment ..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Doing this way the second div will be mantained.